# updating rst2pdf leads to pip uninstall

Tags: software-installation, pip, restructuredtext

I had some problem generating PDF files from reStructuredText, which I thought I could solve with updating rst2pdf.
I got  a `Permission denied` error when I did
`pip install -U rst2pdf`

```
      OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'

$ sudo !!
sudo pip install -U rst2pdf
[sudo] password for root: 
sudo: pip: command not found
$ pip install -U rst2pdf
pip: command not found
```

How can I solve this, and how to prevent it from happening again?

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2802) about this.

Comment: Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692722/installing-virtualenvwrapper-causes-untested-argparse-to-be-installed to?

Comment: If my answer helped you, you could consider voting on it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
easy_install pip
```

if you have `easy_install installed`. If not you can download [`get_pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and then do:

```
python get_pip.py
```

as documented [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)

This was caused by the package `rst2pdf` being (indirectly) depending on `pip`, combined with that you don't have write permissions on `/usr/local` on your system.
The best structural solution would be to run all such programs from a python virtualenv, but since you would have to add the path to the `bin` directory of that virtualenv to your PATH, you might break existing programs that rely
on the systems python and programs it got installed. So if you try that at least use the system python as base for the virtualenv and do not specify a different interpreter with `--python`

The lazy solution I have taken on my system, is that I changed the group permission on `/usr/local` and subdirectories with `sudo chgrp -R grpname /usr/local/*`. That way I am allowed to write in `/usr/local` subdirectories as myself.

Of course it would be nice if `pip` would check up-front if it has the rights to re-install itself **before** uninstalling itself.